# Ideal Conda and pip workflow to get the latest dependencies

Tags: python, pip, conda

I usually start with this conda environment when I have a dependency called `the_dependency`:

```yaml
name: my_app
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.11
  - pip
  - pip:
    - the_dependency
```

I find that `pip` usually finds a more recent version of a package on PyPi, and only when I have architecture-specific trouble I revert to using a Conda version like so:

```yaml
name: my_app
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.11
  - the_dependency
```

Are there better workflows to achieve the same thing?

Comment: so you want something on the line of "choose the most recent installable version of the_dependency from pypi+conda channels"?

Comment: Yes. Without too much friction. Conda can be slow to resolve environments, so I prefer pip. But pip packages sometimes can have architecture -specific issues (GCC, missing libraries), then Conda packages is a fallback.